# Guzzle issue missing-input-secret & missing-input-response

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, laravel-6

I'm using Guzzle 6.5.0 with Laravel 6.7.0 When verifying Google reCaptcha via Guzzle it seems as if the Request Body / `form_params` are not included in the POST params. Below is the PHPUnit 8.5.0 output...

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)#1179 (7) {
 ["method":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  ["requestTarget":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  NULL
  ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri)#1180 (7) {
    ["scheme":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(5) "https"
    ["userInfo":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["host":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(14) "www.google.com"
    ["port":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    NULL
    ["path":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(25) "/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
    ["query":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["fragment":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Host"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "www.google.com"
    }
    ["headers"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Content-Type"]=>
      string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    ["form_params"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["secret"]=>
      string(40) "6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe"
      ["response"]=>
      string(3) "123"
    }
  }
  ["headerNames":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  array(3) {
    ["headers"]=>
    string(7) "headers"
    ["form_params"]=>
    string(11) "form_params"
    ["host"]=>
    string(4) "Host"
  }
  ["protocol":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  string(3) "1.1"
  ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=>
  object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#1182 (7) {
    ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    resource(609) of type (stream)
    ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    int(0)
    ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    string(10) "php://temp"
    ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    array(0) {
   }
 }
```

The `Content-Type` header was set manually. In Laravel, I have access to the secret and the URL so that is not the issue. Especially since the request is sent to the correct URL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the issue explained / why it was not working:

I was confusing Client with Request options:

https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/issues/179

Hope this will help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for the answer, below is my function to validate the Google reCAPTCHA v2.

`$recaptchaResponse` contains the `g-recaptcha-response` parameter value that captured from the form submit.

```
private function validateRecaptcha($recaptchaResponse, $secretKey) {

    try {
        $client = new GuzzleClient([
            'base_uri' => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/',
        ]);

        $payloadJson = [
            'form_params' => [
                'secret' => $secretKey,
                'response' => $recaptchaResponse
            ]
        ];

        $response = $client->post('api/siteverify', $payloadJson);

        $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $dataArray = json_decode($content, true);

        if ($dataArray['success']) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
        // return false on all exceptions
        return false;
    }
}
```